# Python ceasar cipher

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

You will be implementing a shift-cypher.  This type of code shifts every letter by a set amount.

Instructions:
Complete the encode method so that it returns the encoded message.
Complete the decode method so that it returns the decoded message.
In the main method, 
      - prompt the user for the message.
      - prompt the user for the shift amount.
      - Print the message.
      - Call encode with the message and the shift amount.
      - Store the encoded message returned from encode.
      - Print the encoded message.
      - Send the encoded message and the shift amount to the decode method.
      - Print the decoded message.

Tips:
chr(ord('A') + 5) will give you 'F', and chr(ord('F') - 5) will give you 'A'.  You will need to be check for, and adjust for, the times when the shift moves you off the end or beginning of the alphabet.  For example, how will you handle 'B' - 14?
The easiest way to check for upper case or lower case letters is using 'in'.  Refer to the demonstration in class.
Remember, you can compare letters with greater-than and less-than.  'A' > 'B' would be False.
You may assume there is no punctuation (most codes omit punctuation to avoid giving clues about the encoded message).
You do not have to modify the capitalization.
Make sure you preserve spaces. (though a real cypher would not)
You can check to see if your encoding is working using this website.  https://cryptii.com/pipes/caesar-cipher

Sample Input/Output:
    Enter the message: Hello World
    Enter the shift: 10
    Hello World
    Rovvy Gybvn
    Hello World

My Code

```
  def encode(s, shiftamount):
      for x in range(0, s-1):
        if s[x] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
          if chr(ord(x) + shiftamount) > Z : 
            print(chr(ord(s[x])) + (shiftamount - 25),end="") 

          if chr(ord(x) + shiftamount) <= Z :
            print(chr(ord(s[x])) + shiftamount,end="")

        if s[x] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
          if chr(ord(x) + shiftamount) > Z : 
            print(chr(ord(s[x])) + (shiftamount - 25) ,end="") 

          if chr(ord(x) + shiftamount) <= Z :
            print(chr(ord(s[x])) + shiftamount,end="")

      print(chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount,end="")


    #def decode(s, shiftamount):

    def main():
      s = input("Enter the message:")
      shiftamount = input("Enter the shift")
      print(s)
      encode()
      decode()

    ########################################################################
    ###                Do not modify anything below here                 ###
    ########################################################################
    if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208157/discussion-on-question-by-daniil-kharlashko-python-ceasar-cypher).

Comment: I don't see an actual question here, just assignment/homework instructions. This was brought up by other users, too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can help you

```
def encode(s, shiftamount): 
    for x in range(0, len(s)): 
        if s[x] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
            if chr(ord(x) + shiftamount) > Z :
                print(chr(ord(s[x])) + (shiftamount - 25),end="") 
            if chr(ord(x) + shiftamount) <= Z : 
                print(chr(ord(s[x])) + shiftamount,end="") 
         if s[x] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz": 
            if chr(ord(x) + shiftamount) > Z :
                print(chr(ord(s[x])) + (shiftamount - 25) ,end="") 
            if chr(ord(x) + shiftamount) <= Z :
                print(chr(ord(s[x])) + shiftamount,end="") 
                print(chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount,end="") 

def main(): 
    s = input("Enter the message:")
    shiftamount = int(input("Enter the shift"))
    print(s) 
    encode(s, shiftamount)
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Comment: 'def decode(s, shiftamount):
  for y in range(0, len(s)):
    if s[x] == " ":
      print(" ", end="")
    if s[x] in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ":
      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > 'Z' :
        answer += chr(ord(s[x]) - (shiftamount - 26))
      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) <= 'Z' :
        answer += chr(ord(s[x]) - shiftamount)
    if s[x] in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz":
      if chr(ord(s[x]) + shiftamount) > 'z' :
        answer += chr(ord(s[x]) - (shiftamount - 26))
      if chr(ord( s[x] ) + shiftamount) <= 'z' :
        answer += chr(ord(s[x]) - shiftamount)'

Comment: I tried to add the code for the decoder and it doesnt work if you could help me with the decoder receiving the result. Also there is return answer at the end